# Google Translate text only if it is not english

Tags: excel, vba

I am importing google alerts into my excel worksheet , what I am trying to do is only use the google translate code I have if the text is not in English. As the code is very slow. And I import upto 1000 rows of text. The majority of those are already in English. But at present my code translates every row.

```vb
Public Sub Translate()

    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    Dim t As Date
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ftext As String
    Dim x
    Dim y As Long
    Dim translation As Object
    Dim translationText As String

    y = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Google_Notifications")
    For x = 1 To y
        With IE
            .Visible = False
            .Navigate "https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en"
            While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
            ftext = Sheet1.Range("C" & x).Value
            .Document.querySelector("#source").Value = ftext
            While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
            t = Timer
            Do
                On Error Resume Next
                Set translation = .Document.querySelector(".tlid-translation.translation")
                translationText = translation.textContent
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
            Loop While translationText = vbNullString
            Sheet1.Range("C" & x).Value = translationText
            Sheet1.Range("E" & x).Value = "Translated"
            .Quit
            Set IE = Nothing
            Set translation = Nothing
            translationText = ""
        End With
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: To improve code performance you may: 1) use XHR instead of IE, 2) use asynchronous XHR, 3) check for non-ASCII chars before making the request.

Comment: Thanks . How would I do this and what is XHR

Comment: Try to start from [some examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+vba+translate.google.com+xmlhttprequest)